# Invalid gemspec ruby color box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, colorbox

```
mustdos@antix1:~
$ rails new demo
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/rails-assets-colorbox.gemspec]: stack level too deep
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    4: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:301:in `activate_bin_path'
    3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:301:in `synchronize'
    2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:303:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:236:in `finish_resolve'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:167:in `require': CRITICAL: RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.owned?: before false -> after true (RuntimeError)
```

How do I fix this issue?

was following this: tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-tutorial.pdf and accidentally installed ruby and ruby-* before rbenv. Should I just clean=up and start over?

Comment: mustdos@antix1:~
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: $ rails -v
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/rails-assets-colorbox.gemspec]: stack level too deep
Traceback (most recent call last):
 5: from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
 4: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:301:in `activate_bin_path'

Comment: 3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:301:in `synchronize'
 2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:303:in `block in activate_bin_path'
 1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:236:in `finish_resolve'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:167:in `require': CRITICAL: RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.owned?: before false -> after true (RuntimeError)

Comment: Used:  mustdos@antix1:~
$ rbenv install --list | grep rails | less
couldn't find rails in here

Comment: was following this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-tutorial.pdf

Comment: `rbenv install --list` has nothing to do with rails, that will display the ruby versions installed. To see your rails versions installed, try with `gem list | grep rails`. Any chance that rails is running from a different gem source? check `which ruby` and `which gem`, both should point to `.rbenv/shims` folder, `which rails` should also display `rails: aliased to _rails_command`. Finally, any additional info, please edit your question instead of adding new comments.

Comment: mustdos@antix1:~ $ which ruby /usr/bin/ruby mustdos@antix1:~ $ which gem /usr/bin/gem 
gem list | grep rails gave me a very long list of rails related stuff 
Note: I installed ruby before I looked into the manual; even before installing rbenv

Comment: Well, that probably explain your issue, you're using system's ruby instead of the rbenv version. Try reinstalling rbenv, but probably you haven't loaded rbenv into your `.bashrc` file, when you reinstall rbenv, pay attention to the messages post-install.

Comment: Turns out, that manual was outdated and found my answers on different threads...